# SPARK REST API: Why executorCpuTime is much smaller than taskTime?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a stage with one task.
I'm trying to understand why the taskMetrics.**taskTime** (7051 / 10^3 = 7.0 seconds) is so much bigger than the taskMetrics.**executorCpuTime** (1058675760 / 10^9 = 1.05 seconds).
There are other time fields like executorDeserializeTime, executorDeserializeCpuTime, jvmGcTime, resultSerializationTime, fetchWaitTime and writeTime, but they don't sum up to the taskTime.
Where did the extra time come from?

Is there some place where all these fields are documented?

````
  "status" : "COMPLETE",
  "stageId" : 239,
  "attemptId" : 0,
  "numTasks" : 1,
  "numActiveTasks" : 0,
  "numCompleteTasks" : 1,
  "numFailedTasks" : 0,
  "numKilledTasks" : 0,
  "numCompletedIndices" : 1,
  "executorRunTime" : 7051,
  "executorCpuTime" : 1058675760,
  "submissionTime" : "2019-02-17T15:46:36.922GMT",
  "firstTaskLaunchedTime" : "2019-02-17T15:46:36.931GMT",
  "completionTime" : "2019-02-17T15:46:44.120GMT",
  "inputBytes" : 0,
  "inputRecords" : 410409,
  "outputBytes" : 0,
  "outputRecords" : 0,
  "shuffleReadBytes" : 0,
  "shuffleReadRecords" : 0,
  "shuffleWriteBytes" : 3161381,
  "shuffleWriteRecords" : 410409,
  "memoryBytesSpilled" : 0,
  "diskBytesSpilled" : 0,
  "name" : "jdbc at <unknown>:0",
  "details" : "org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc(DataFrameWriter.scala:501)\nsun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor197.invoke(Unknown Source)\nsun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\njava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\npy4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)\npy4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)\npy4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)\npy4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)\npy4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)\npy4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)\njava.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)",
  "schedulingPool" : "default",
  "rddIds" : [ 771, 770, 759 ],
  "accumulatorUpdates" : [ ],
  "tasks" : {
    "665" : {
      "taskId" : 665,
      "index" : 0,
      "attempt" : 0,
      "launchTime" : "2019-02-17T15:46:36.931GMT",
      "duration" : 7188,
      "executorId" : "driver",
      "host" : "localhost",
      "status" : "SUCCESS",
      "taskLocality" : "PROCESS_LOCAL",
      "speculative" : false,
      "accumulatorUpdates" : [ ],
      "taskMetrics" : {
        "executorDeserializeTime" : 2,
        "executorDeserializeCpuTime" : 1444953,
        "executorRunTime" : 7051,
        "executorCpuTime" : 1058675760,
        "resultSize" : 1396,
        "jvmGcTime" : 0,
        "resultSerializationTime" : 0,
        "memoryBytesSpilled" : 0,
        "diskBytesSpilled" : 0,
        "peakExecutionMemory" : 0,
        "inputMetrics" : {
          "bytesRead" : 0,
          "recordsRead" : 410409
        },
        "outputMetrics" : {
          "bytesWritten" : 0,
          "recordsWritten" : 0
        },
        "shuffleReadMetrics" : {
          "remoteBlocksFetched" : 0,
          "localBlocksFetched" : 0,
          "fetchWaitTime" : 0,
          "remoteBytesRead" : 0,
          "remoteBytesReadToDisk" : 0,
          "localBytesRead" : 0,
          "recordsRead" : 0
        },
        "shuffleWriteMetrics" : {
          "bytesWritten" : 3161381,
          "writeTime" : 195639346,
          "recordsWritten" : 410409
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "executorSummary" : {
    "driver" : {
      "taskTime" : 7188,
      "failedTasks" : 0,
      "succeededTasks" : 1,
      "killedTasks" : 0,
      "inputBytes" : 0,
      "inputRecords" : 410409,
      "outputBytes" : 0,
      "outputRecords" : 0,
      "shuffleRead" : 0,
      "shuffleReadRecords" : 0,
      "shuffleWrite" : 3161381,
      "shuffleWriteRecords" : 410409,
      "memoryBytesSpilled" : 0,
      "diskBytesSpilled" : 0
    }
  },
  "killedTasksSummary" : { }
} ]```
````